# Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: Unknown database

Tags: sql, node.js, database

This was my full error, I installed all the coorect dependencies but I couldnt figure out why I was still getting this same Error over and over again.

> ➜  Unsolved git:(main) ✗ node server.js

Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: Unknown database 'sequelize_library'
at /Users/usersname/Desktop/projects/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)

at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/userName/Desktop/projects/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/userName/Desktop/projects/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/userName/Desktop/projects//node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/userName/Desktop/projects/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:725:18)
at _drainQueueStep (/Users/userName/Desktop/projects//node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
at _drainQueue (/Users/userName/Desktop/projects/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
at Async._drainQueues (/Users/userName/Desktop/projects/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/userName/Desktop/projects/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)

Answer (score 0):

Getting this erros with all the right depencies installed. What worked for me was

> (All commands go in terminal)

going into my sql with `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -p`

Entering my password then ran `source schema.sql` which held my create database code

I `quit` SQL

& ran `node server.js`